# Using apache web server proxy to apache tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, websocket, stomp

According to [apaches](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) documentation, wstunnel was added in 2.4 and I should be able to route traffic.

I have the following setup

Apache tomcat running on 8081 and 8444.

There are static files (html/js) as well as groovy/grails (war) files being served from Tomcat

I have proxied `8081 <- 80` and `8444 <- 443`

Meaning I can go to `http://domain/app` and see what I would have to otherwise go to `http://domain:8081/app` to see. [This is working just fine]

However, within the static javascript/html pages, there is a connection back to the tomcat using websocket. My app attempts to connect back to an app called `inf` and this fails.

This proxy/connection fails.

I see in the log that httpd (apache) was unable to find the correct protocol for `/inf/stomp/getInfo` which is the url to the websocket on the backend

I have attempted to follow [this posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784658/using-go-websocket-behind-apache-mod-proxy-wstunnel/18822599#18822599) notes as well as proper ordering mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649241/reverse-proxy-with-websocket-mod-proxy-wstunnel)

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 443
ServerName mydomain
<VirtualHost *:443>

<Proxy *>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
</Proxy>

SSLEngine On
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/ssl/ssl.key
RequestHeader set Front-End-Https "On"
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyVerify none 
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
LogLevel debug


ProxyPass /mainView https://mydomain:8443/mainView
ProxyPassReverse /mainView https://mydomain:8443/mainView

ProxyPass /cas https://mydomain:8443/cas
ProxyPassReverse /cas https://mydomain:8443/cas

# <not working as it should>
ProxyPass /inf/ ws://mydomain:8081/inf/
ProxyPassReverse /inf/ ws://mydomain:8081/inf/
# </not working as it should>

ProxyPass /inf/ wss://mydomain:8444/inf/
ProxyPassReverse /inf/ wss://mydomain:8444/inf/



ProxyPass /inf-app https://mydomain:8444/
ProxyPassReverse /inf-app  https://mydomain:8444/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realise you have two: **ProxyPass /inf/** blocks, if you have both a secure and insecure virtualHost you'll need move the **ws:** version to the port 80 virtualhost. There's also a duplicate **SSLProxyEngine on**

As to fixing your issue see: [tunneling secure websocket connections with apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache), inparticular the: **--enable-proxy_wstunnel=shared** text