# Apache websocket reverse proxy

Tags: java, apache, websocket

I have implemented apache websocket API in my project, which is working all fine on my local. Over http and https, but when i moved the project to upper environment where we don't use ip address of machines directly instead refer them using URL.
So earlier i used to open websocket connection as follows
**webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://myApp(ip)/endpointName");** OR
**webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://myApp(ip)/endpointName");**

But after moving on other evironments it's not working anymore as there might be part of reverse proxy (I dont know much about Apache server sertup). We have included WS_TUNNELING module for web socket reverse proxy to work.
But still not able to find the proper solution.

What I want is, I should be able to open web socket using
**webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://myApp.com/endpointName");**

have tried following links
[ws_tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649241/reverse-proxy-with-websocket-mod-proxy-wstunnel)
and
[ws_tunneling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468154/tunneling-secure-websocket-connections-with-apache)

Please let me know

Comment: I don't want to open any port directly, is it possible with reverse proxy and ws_tunneling or i have to open a port in order use websocket ?